# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token on some hosting providers

Tags: php, json, wordpress

When the VIN number is added in the admin and a button is pressed to get the data, in some hosting providers I'm getting an error and spinning loading wheel of death, while other providers and even in localhost I get the info correctly. Why is this not consistent and what I can do to make it work all the time?

The error on the Google Chrome console is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

and if I click on the arrow to expand the error it will only show [object][object].

Here is the code:

```
<?php add_action('wp_ajax_rw_api_data', 'rw_api_data'); function rw_api_data(){
if ( isset($_POST["vin"]) && strlen($_POST["vin"]) === 17 ){

    $api_key = get_option('Edmund_API');
    $vin = $_POST["vin"];

    // get basic details
    $url = sprintf( "https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/vins/%s?&fmt=json&api_key=%s" , $vin , $api_key );

    $get_response = wp_remote_get($url); 

    if( !is_wp_error( $get_response ) ) :

        $basic_data = json_decode( $get_response["body"], TRUE);

        $style_id = isset($_POST["style"]) && $_POST["style"] ? $_POST["style"] : false;
        $post_id = (int)$_POST["ID"];

        if( !isset( $basic_data["errorType"] ) ) :

            $styles = array();
            $elements = array();

            foreach( $basic_data['years'] as $year ):

                foreach( $year["styles"] as $style ) :

                    $styles[] = array(
                        "year" => $year["year"],
                        "style" => $style
                    );

                endforeach;

            endforeach;


            if( count( $styles ) === 1 || $style_id !== false ) :

                $style_id = $style_id ? $style_id : $basic_data['years'][0]["styles"][0]["id"];


                // get equipment details
                $url = sprintf( "https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/styles/%s/equipment?fmt=json&api_key=%s",$style_id,$api_key);
                $get_response = wp_remote_get($url); 

                if( !is_wp_error( $get_response ) ) :

                    $equipment_data = json_decode($get_response["body"], TRUE);

                    $features = array();
                    // Year
                    $elements["year"] = $basic_data['years'][0]["year"];

                    foreach( $basic_data["colors"] as $color ):

                        if( $color['category'] == "Interior" || $color['category'] == "Exterior" ) :

                            $color_key = strtolower($color['category']);

                            foreach( $color["options"] as $color_option ) :

                                if( !empty( $elements[$color_key] ) ) $elements[$color_key] .= ", " ; else $elements[$color_key]  = "";

                                $elements[$color_key] .= $color_option["name"];

                            endforeach;

                        endif;

                    endforeach;

                    // Vehicle Type
                    switch( strtolower( $basic_data["categories"]["vehicleStyle"] ) ) :

                        case "sedan" :
                            $elements["vehicletype"] = "Sedans and Coupes";
                        break;

                        case "coupe" :
                            $elements["vehicletype"] = "Sports Cars";
                        break;

                        case "wagon" :
                            $elements["vehicletype"] = "Wagons";
                        break;

                        case "passenger minivan" :
                            $elements["vehicletype"] = "Minivans and Vans";
                        break;

                        case "crew cab pickup" :
                            $elements["vehicletype"] = "Pickup Trucks";
                        break;

                        case "4dr hatchback" :
                            $elements["vehicletype"] = "Hybrids";
                        break;

                        case "convertible" :
                            $elements["vehicletype"] = "Convertibles";
                        break;

                        case "4dr suv" :
                            $elements["vehicletype"] = "Sport Utilities";
                        break;

                        default :
                            $elements["vehicletype"] = $basic_data["categories"]["vehicleStyle"];
                        break;

                    endswitch;

                    // Drive
                    $elements['drive'] = $basic_data['drivenWheels'];

                    // Transmission
                    switch( $basic_data["transmission"]["transmissionType"] ) :

                        case "AUTOMATIC" :
                            $elements['transmission'] = 'Automatic';
                        break;

                        case "MANUAL" :
                            $elements['transmission'] = 'Manual';
                        break;

                        case "SEMI-AUTO" :
                            $elements['transmission'] = 'Semi-Auto';
                        break;

                        default :
                            $elements['transmission'] = 'Other';
                        break;

                    endswitch;

                    // VIN
                    $elements['vin'] = $basic_data["vin"];  

                    // Engine Size
                    $elements['enginesize'] = $basic_data['engine']['size'];
                    // Number of Cylinders
                    $elements['cylinders'] = $basic_data['engine']['cylinder'];
                    // Horsepower
                    $elements['horsepower'] = $basic_data['engine']['horsepower'];

                    $elements['enginetype'] = $basic_data['engine']['type'];

                    $equipment_relations = array(
                        "Air Conditioning" => array(
                            "Front Air Conditioning" => "FRONT_AIR_CONDITIONING"
                        ),
                        "Brake System" => array(
                            "Front Brake Type" => "FRONT_BRAKE_TYPE",
                            "Rear Brake Diameter" => "REAR_BRAKE_DIAMETER",
                            "Braking Assist" => "BRAKING_ASSIST",
                            "Antilock Braking System" => "ANTILOCK_BRAKING_SYSTEM"
                        ),
                        "Security" => array(
                            "Power Door Locks" => "POWER_DOOR_LOCKS",
                            "Anti Theft Alarm System" => "ANTI_THEFT_ALARM_SYSTEM"
                        ),
                        "Mirrors" => array(
                            "1st Row Vanity Mirrors" => "1ST_ROW_VANITY_MIRRORS",
                            "Heated Driver Side Mirror" => "HEATED_DRIVER_SIDE_MIRROR",
                            "Heated Passenger Side Mirror" => "HEATED_PASSENGER_SIDE_MIRROR",
                            "Auto Dimming Rearview Mirror" => "AUTO_DIMMING_REARVIEW_MIRROR"
                        ),
                        "Tires" => array(
                            "option" =>  "tires"
                        ),
                        "Suspension" => array(
                            "Rear Suspension Type" => "REAR_SUSPENSION_TYPE",
                            "Independent Suspension" => "INDEPENDENT_SUSPENSION",
                            "Front Suspension Type" => "FRONT_SUSPENSION_TYPE"
                        ),
                        "Airbags" => array(
                            "Passenger Airbag" => "PASSENGER_AIRBAG"
                        ),
                        "Specifications" => array(
                            "Fuel Capacity" => "fuelcapacity",
                            "Curb Weight" => "curbweight",
                            "Epa City Mpg" => "EPA_CITY_MPG",
                            "Epa Highway Mpg" => "EPA_HIGHWAY_MPG"
                        ),
                        "Cargo Dimensions" => array(
                            "Max Cargo Capacity" => "MAX_CARGO_CAPACITY"
                        ),
                        "Exterior Dimensions" => array(
                            "Overall Width Without Mirrors" => "width",
                            "Overall Height" => "height",
                            "Overall Length" => "overalllength",
                            "Wheelbase" => "wheelbase"
                        ),
                        "Interior Dimensions" => array(
                            "1st Row Head Room" => "headroom",
                            "1st Row Leg Room" => "legroom",
                            "1st Row Head Room" => "headroom"
                        ),
                        "Steering Wheel" => array(
                            "Audio Controls On Steering Wheel" => "AUDIO_CONTROLS_ON_STEERING_WHEEL",
                            "Cruise Controls On Steering Wheel" => "CRUISE_CONTROLS_ON_STEERING_WHEEL"
                        ),
                        "Misc. Exterior Features" => array(
                            "Roof Rack" => "ROOF_RACK",
                            "Running Boards" => "RUNNING_BOARDS"
                        ),
                        "Misc. Interior Features" => array(
                            "Cruise Control" => "CRUISE_CONTROL"
                        ),
                        "2nd Row Seats" => array(
                            "Folding 2nd Row" => "FOLDING_2ND_ROW"
                        ),
                        "Power Outlets" => array(
                            "1st Row Power Outlet" => "1ST_ROW_POWER_OUTLET",
                            "Cargo Area Power Outlet" => "CARGO_AREA_POWER_OUTLET"
                        ),
                        "Trailer Hitch" => "TRAILER_HITCH",
                        "Trailer Wiring" => "TRAILER_WIRING",
                        "Running Boards" => "RUNNING_BOARDS"
                    );

                    $tags_relations = array(

                        "Airbags" => array(
                            "Side Airbags" => "name",
                            "Passenger Airbag" => "name",
                            "Head Airbags" => "name",
                            "Knee Airbags" => "name",
                            "Hip Airbags" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Air Conditioning" => array(
                            "Front Air Conditioning" => "ac",
                            "Air Filtration" => "name",
                            "Sun Sensor" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Audio System" => array(
                            "Cd Player" => "name",
                            "Cd Mp3 Playback" => "mp3",
                            "Radio" => "radio",
                            "Satellite Radio" => "name",
                            "Usb Connection" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Brake System" => array(
                            "Antilock Braking System" => "abs",
                            "Braking Assist" => "name",
                            "Brake Drying" => "name",
                            "Emergency Braking Preparation" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Convertible Roof" => array(
                            "Convertible Roof" => "name",
                            "Convertible Window" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Doors" => array(
                            "Number Of Doors" => "num_doors"
                        ),
                        "Driver Seat" => array(
                            "Heated Driver Seat" => "name",
                            "Height Adjustable Driver Seat" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Drive Type" => array(
                            "Driven Wheels" => "driven_wheels"
                        ),
                        "Exterior Lights" => array(
                            "Front Fog Lights" => "name",
                            "Headlights Auto Delay" => "had",
                            "Daytime Running Lights" => "name",
                            "Headlights Dusk Sensor" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Front Passenger Seat" => array(
                            "Heated Passenger Seat" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Instrumentation" => array(
                            "Tachometer" => "name",
                            "Low Fuel Level Indicator" => "name",
                            "Tire Pressure Monitoring System" => "name",
                            "Compass" => "name",
                            "External Temperature Gauge" => "name",
                            "Head Up Display" => "name",
                            "Trip Computer" => "name",
                            "Transmission Temperature Gauge" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Misc. Exterior Features" => array(
                            "Rear Spoiler" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Misc. Interior Features" => array(
                            "Cruise Control" => "name",
                            "Cargo Area Light" => "name",
                            "Reading Lights" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Mirrors" => array(
                            "Heated Exterior Mirrors" => "name",
                            "Heated Passenger Side Mirror" => "name",
                            "Auto Dimming Rearview Mirror" => "name",
                            "Auto Dimming Side Mirrors" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Mobile Connectivity" => array(
                            "Phone" => "name",
                            "Bluetooth" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Parking Aid" => array(
                            "Parking Sensors" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Security" => array(
                            "Engine Immobilizer" => "name",
                            "Anti Theft Alarm System" => "alarm",
                            "Power Door Locks" => "door_locks",
                            "2 Stage Unlocking" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Spare Tire/Wheel" => array(
                            "Tire Repair Kit" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Standard Audio" => array(
                            "Cd Player" => "name",
                            "Cd Mp3 Playback" => "mp3",
                            "Radio" => "radio",
                            "Satellite Radio" => "name",
                            "Usb Connection" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Steering Wheel" => array(
                            "Audio Controls On Steering Whee" => "name",
                            "Phone Controls On Steering Whee" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Sunroof" => array(
                            "Sunroof" => "name"
                        ),
                        "Windows" => array(
                            "Rear Defogger" => "name",
                            "Rain Sensing Front Wipers" => "name",
                            "Remote Window Operation" => "name"
                        )
                    );

                    foreach( $equipment_data["equipment"] as $equipment_item ) :

                        $ename =  $equipment_item["name"];


                        // counting number of seats
                        if( $ename == "Seating Configuration" ) : 

                            $elements['seatingcapacity'] = 0;

                            foreach( $equipment_item["attributes" ] as $attribute ) :

                                $elements['seatingcapacity'] += intval($attribute["value"]);

                            endforeach;

                        // getting engine details
                        elseif( $ename == "Engine" ) :

                            if( !$elements['enginesize'] ):
                                $elements['enginesize'] = $equipment_item["size"];
                            endif;

                            if( !$elements['cylinders'] ):
                                $elements['cylinders'] = $equipment_item["cylinder"];
                            endif;

                            if( !$elements['horsepower'] ):
                                $elements['horsepower'] = $equipment_item["horsepower"];
                            endif;

                            if( !$elements['enginetype'] ):
                                $elements['enginetype'] = $equipment_item["type"];
                            endif;

                        else :

                            // relation exists
                            if( isset( $equipment_relations[ $ename ] ) ) :


                                if( is_array( $equipment_relations[ $ename ] ) ) :

                                    foreach( $equipment_item["attributes" ] as $attribute ) :

                                        $aname = $attribute["name"];

                                        if( isset( $equipment_relations[ $ename ][ $aname ] ) ) :

                                            $elements[ $equipment_relations[ $ename ][ $aname ] ] = $attribute["value"];

                                        endif;

                                    endforeach;

                                    if( isset( $equipment_relations[ $ename ][ "option" ] ) && isset( $equipment_item["options" ] ) && count( $equipment_item["options" ] ) > 0  ) :

                                        $elements[  $equipment_relations[ $ename ][ "option" ] ] = $equipment_item["options" ][0]["name"];

                                    endif;

                                else :

                                    $elements[ $equipment_relations[ $ename ] ] = "Yes";

                                endif;

                            endif;

                        endif;

                        if( isset( $tags_relations[ $ename ] ) ) :

                            foreach( $equipment_item["attributes" ] as $attribute ) :

                                $aname = $attribute["name"];

                                if( isset( $tags_relations[ $ename ][ $aname ] ) ) :

                                    if( $tags_relations[ $ename ][ $aname ] === "name" ):

                                        $features[ $aname ] = $aname;

                                    else :

                                        $features[ $tags_relations[ $ename ][ $aname ] ] = $attribute["value"];

                                    endif;

                                endif;

                            endforeach;

                        endif;

                    endforeach;

                    /******** START FEATURES TAGS *************/

                    $tags = array();

                    // generate tags from matched equipment
                    foreach( $features as $feature_name=>$feature_value ) :

                        switch( $feature_name ) :

                            case "num_doors" : 
                                $tags[] = $feature_value . " Door"; 
                            break;
                            case "abs" : 
                                switch( $feature_value ) :
                                    case "4-wheel ABS" : 
                                        $tags[] = "4-wheel ABS Brakes";
                                    break;
                                    default :
                                        $tags[] = $feature_value;
                                    break;
                                endswitch;
                            break;
                            case "ac" :
                                $tags[] = "Air Conditioning"; 
                            break;
                            case "heated_exterior_mirrors" :
                                $tags[] = "Heated Exterior Mirrors";
                            break;
                            case "driven_wheels" :
                                $tags[] = ucwords(strtolower($feature_value));
                            break;
                            case "had" :
                                $tags[] = "Headlights Off Auto Delay";
                            break;
                            case "mp3" :
                                $tags[] = "mp3";
                            break;
                            case "radio" :
                                $tags[] =  $feature_value . " Radio";
                            break;

                            default : 
                                $tags[] = $feature_value;
                            break;

                        endswitch;

                    endforeach;


                    // Generate tags from element values 
                    foreach( $elements as $element_key=>$element_value ) :

                            switch( $element_key ) :
                                case "seatingcapacity" : 
                                     $tags[] = $element_value . " Seats";
                                break;
                                case "TRAILER_HITCH" :
                                    $tags[] = "Trailer Hitch";
                                break;
                                case "TRAILER_WIRING" :
                                    $tags[] = "Trailer Wiring";
                                break;
                                case "RUNNING_BOARDS" :
                                    $tags[] = "Running Boards";
                                break;

                            endswitch;
                    endforeach;

                    /******** END FEATURES TAGS *************/

                    if( $elements["CRUISE_CONTROLS_ON_STEERING_WHEEL"] == "cruise controls" ) :
                        $elements["CRUISE_CONTROLS_ON_STEERING_WHEEL"] = "Yes";
                    endif;

                    if( $elements["AUDIO_CONTROLS_ON_STEERING_WHEEL"] == "audio controls" ) :
                        $elements["AUDIO_CONTROLS_ON_STEERING_WHEEL"] = "Yes";
                    endif;

                    $elements['Make'] = $basic_data["make"]["name"];
                    $elements['Model'] = $basic_data["model"]["name"];  

                    // Post Data
                    $elements['post_name'] = $basic_data["model"]["id"];
                    $elements['post_title'] = $elements['Make'] . ' ' . $elements['Model'] . ' ' . $elements["year"];

                    $response["tags"] = join(",",$tags);

                    $makemodel_terms = array();

                    $make_term = term_exists( $basic_data["make"]["name"] , 'makemodel' , 0 );


                    if( $make_term !== 0 && $make_term !== null ) :

                        $makemodel_terms[] = (int)$make_term["term_id"];

                    else :

                        $make_term = wp_insert_term( $basic_data["make"]["name"] , 'makemodel');

                        if( !is_wp_error( $make_term ) ) :

                            $makemodel_terms[] = (int)$make_term["term_id"];

                        endif;

                    endif;

                    $model_term = term_exists( $basic_data["model"]["name"] , 'makemodel' , $make_term["term_id"] );

                    if( $model_term !== 0 && $model_term !== null ) :

                        $makemodel_terms[] = (int)$model_term["term_id"];

                    else :

                        $model_term = wp_insert_term( $basic_data["model"]["name"] , 'makemodel', array( "parent" => $make_term["term_id"] ));

                        if( !is_wp_error( $model_term ) ) :

                            $makemodel_terms[] = $model_term["term_id"];

                        endif;

                    endif;

                    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $makemodel_terms, 'makemodel' );

                    ob_start();

                    wp_terms_checklist( $post_id, array( 'taxonomy' => 'makemodel', 'popular_cats' => wp_popular_terms_checklist( 'makemodel' , "" , 10, false ) ) );

                    $elements["makemodelchecklist"] = ob_get_clean();

                    ob_start();

                    wp_popular_terms_checklist( 'makemodel' );

                    $elements["makemodelchecklist-pop"] = ob_get_clean();

                    //$elements["newtag[features]"] = join(",",$features);

                    $response["elements"] = $elements;

                    $response["error"] = false;

                else :

                    $response["error"] = true;
                    $response["error_message"] = $get_response->get_error_message();

                endif;

            else :

                $response["styles"] = "<option value='' >Select specific style</option>";

                $current_year = false;

                foreach( $styles as $style ) :

                    if( $current_year !== $style["year"] ) :

                        if( $current_year !== false ) :

                            $response["styles"] .= "</optgroup>";

                        endif;

                        $response["styles"] .= sprintf( "<optgroup label='%s' >" , "Year " . $style["year"] );

                        $current_year = $style["year"];

                    endif;

                    $response["styles"] .= sprintf( "<option value='%s' >%s</option>" , $style["style"]["id"] , $style["style"]["name"] );

                endforeach;

                $response["styles"] .= "</optgroup>";

                $response["error"] = true;

            endif;

        else :

            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["error_message"] = $basic_data["message"];

        endif;

    else :

        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["error_message"] = $get_response->get_error_message();

    endif;

    header("Content-Type:application/json");
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}

}
?>
```

The problem does not seem to be dependent of an OS or browser.

Comment: id imagine some hosts will have curl disabled or a firewall rule to prevent access to sites not whitelisted.

Comment: That is what I was thinking tools it is working on some servers and others not, is there any way to check if curl is enabled in the script and if it is disabled display an alert or message?

Comment: @David I just did `<?php function _is_curl_installed() {
    if  (in_array  ('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Ouput text to user based on test
if (_is_curl_installed()) {
  echo "cURL is <span style=\"color:#4fa361;\">installed</span> on this server";
} else {
  echo "cURL is <span style=\"color:#dc4f49\">not installed</span> on this server";
}

?> `   and it I received  cURL Is installed on the server so it looks like that is not causing the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token error.

Comment: none the less there is an error, your unexpected token is something other than json, dont forget the firewall restriction will show curl as open but no file gets opened. but you should `console.log()` your response from ajax before decoding it this will give you the error.

Comment: @David thanks for your reply, can you be kind enough to guide me with the console.log function and where to add/check for the message as I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: `console.log(response);` i cant tell you where to add it, it will be in a js file or on the html template for the page you are using, if its admin and a meta box it could be in the custom meta box called. but try searching for .ajax in your files. Might be worth getting another dev to do this if your not familiar it won't cost much to do this and add a timeout, but solving the connection issues might be tricky, most plugins have a connection test in the admin screen to warn users that a connection is not possible

Comment: I agree with @David: if you are not a developer, it is not realistic either to learn what you need in a short timeframe, or to be guided through in a step-by-step fashion on _Stack Overflow_. Find a more reliable developer `:-)`.

Comment: However if you can add more details to this question, readers may be able to get you started. In what way does this error manifest itself? The similar questions in the sidebar suggest this is an error from JavaScript. Have you tried a range of browsers or operating systems to see if it is dependent on those things?

Comment: @halfer is not dependent of an OS or browser, it is something in the hosting provider that blocks the call or similar, localhost or other server providers work correctly, sometimes GoDaddy or Bluehost will show this error.

Comment: @david I do have a JS file where all jQuery functionality is stored, do you think you can post a simple console.log  function to check for this script error?

Comment: Would you add a screenshot of what the error looks like? For a provider where it does not work, does it always not work, or is it sporadic?

Comment: @halfer the error on the Google chrome console is  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"  and if I click on the arrow to expand the error it will only show [object][object] thanks fro your help.